How careful should I be when using SetIsOriginAllowed?
I found the following code in Startup.cs:
app.UseCors(options => options
          .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => origin.EndsWith("SomeWebsite.com"))
          .AllowAnyMethod()
          .AllowAnyHeader()
          .AllowCredentials()
          .SetPreflightMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2520)
    )

I was concerned with the EndsWith() method.
With the current state of this code, would this mean a website such as maliciousSomeWebsite.com could perform a CSRF attack?
Should the code instead be changed to origin.EndsWith(".SomeWebsite.com")?

Consider using a different title for your question. "Best practice" looks opinionated

You should indeed be wary of custom callback/hook functionalities like SetIsOriginAllowed in CORS middleware libraries.

I think it is safer to check the main domain explicitly and add wildcard checking for the subdomains, this should work:
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                    builder => builder
                    .WithOrigins
                    (
                        "https://*.SomeWebsite.com"
                    )
                    .SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader());
            });

